# Insert space in a string at 8th column using sed

Tags: unix, sed

Need to insert a space to separate the date and time at the 8th column.

Input file:

```
AAA|detail_hist|count|||766855||2014-08-2019:49:57
BBB|detail_hist|count|||766855||2014-07-2019:49:57
```

Required output:

```
AAA|detail_hist|count|||766855||2014-08-20 19:49:57
BBB|detail_hist|count|||766855||2014-07-20 19:49:57
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you asked for a sed solution but when you're talking about modifying specific field numbers you should really consider awk since it has built in support for numbered fields:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {sub(/.{10}/,"& ",$8)} 1' file
AAA|detail_hist|count|||766855||2014-08-20 19:49:57
BBB|detail_hist|count|||766855||2014-07-20 19:49:57
```

Comment: While this works right off the bat on my BSD and GNU `awk` v4 I have to enable `--re-interval` on GNU `awk` v3.*. I always wondered that if `awk` uses ERE by default why was that extra option necessary?

Comment: Because RE Intervals weren't original part of the ERE syntax so gawk originally decided to make `{10}` literally means the characters { then 10 then } for backward compatibility. They changed that decision in gawk 4 so RE Intervals would be enabled by default.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
$ sed -r 's/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/& /' file
AAA|detail_hist|count|||766855||2014-08-20 19:49:57
BBB|detail_hist|count|||766855||2014-07-20 19:49:57
```

It looks for a block of `XXXX-YY-ZZ` and replaces it with a `XXXX-YY-ZZ` (that is, the block + space).

If `-r` is not supported, you need to escape every `{}`:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}/& /' file
```

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you could learn something from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's/^\(.*\)\([0-9][0-9]:.*:.*\)$/\1 \2/g' file
AAA|detail_hist|count|||766855||2014-08-20 19:49:57
BBB|detail_hist|count|||766855||2014-07-20 19:49:57
```

Comment: a touch simpler: `sed -r 's/([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})$/ \1/' file` -- the "g" flag is not necessary since the regex is anchored and thus can only match once per line.

Answer (score 0):

if structure is as in sample (nothing behing 8th column)

```
sed 's/.\{8\}$/ &/' YourFile
```

with space security

```
sed 's/.\{8\} *$/ &/' YourFile
```

`--posix` with gnu sed